# How to check if data has changed in database

Tags: sql-server, database

In order to create a Dashboard I need to work on a database that I do not have information about. The data in the DataBase is updated through a particular management interface and I do not know where it is updated on the DB. Is there a way to check for data updates without the tables names or columns names?

Thanks

Comment: Ummm.....just curious how you expect to generate a dashboard for a database you know nothing about. But to answer your question....what data do you care about? Every value in every row of every table? You could generate some triggers but to what end? This is really not an answerable question.

Comment: Actually, @SeanLange, it _is_ answerable as posed, but the answer is "no, there's no way to do that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that knowing nothing about the database will not get you very far, but you can get some information about table updates without knowing what you're looking for. Whether or not it's useful is a different question.

The included code leverages `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` to identify the last time a user update was performed on the table. This works for heaps as well as indexed tables and the `user_update` value includes inserts, deletes, and updates. The `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` view will include information only for tables that have been interacted. To work around that I `UNION ALL` with a second query to get the relevant object information for tables that aren't found in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. This gives a complete view of the table objects regardless of whether or not they've been used since the service started. You may not care about that at all and could strip it out.

Again, this may not be helpful, but your question was just "Is there a way to check for data updates without the tables names or columns names?" and the answer to that specific question is yes.

**Caveats:**

- The `user_update` value is simply an incrementing counter of update actions. This will not let you know what the update was or how many updates have occured since X point in time, but it will let you know the last time a table was updated.
- This information does not persist beyond a service restart, so if a table was updated right before a restart, you wouldn't know.
- The provided script is database specific, meaning it only returns information about the datbase it runs in. You could use something like `sp_MSforeachdb` to run against everything though.

And the code...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        @@servername as servername 
        , DB_NAME(database_id) as DatabaseName
        , u.object_id
        , SchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(u.object_id, database_Id)  
        , TableName = OBJECT_NAME(u.object_id, database_id) 
        , Writes =  SUM(user_updates)
        , LastUpdate = CASE WHEN MAX(u.last_user_update) IS NULL THEN CAST('17530101' AS DATETIME) ELSE MAX(u.last_user_update) END
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats u
    JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON u.index_id = i.index_id
    AND u.object_id = i.object_id
    WHERE u.database_id = DB_ID()
    GROUP BY database_id, u.object_id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        @@servername as servername
        , DB_NAME() as DatabaseName 
        , o.object_id
        , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id, db_id())
        , object_name(o.object_id, db_id())
        , 0
        , CAST('17530101' AS DATETIME) 
    FROM sys.indexes i
    JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE o.type_desc in ('user_table')
    and i.index_id NOT IN (select s.index_id from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s where s.object_id=i.object_id 
    and i.index_id=s.index_id and database_id = db_id(db_name()) )
) AS temp 
ORDER BY writes DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for, I hope it will help me with to move on with the project